# Django Manager isn't accessible via CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail instances

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have this model CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail, Product, Customer, I just want that if the same productID and same CustomerID exists in the CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail model, the quantity will add 1 if the same productID and same CustomerID exists in the CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.

This is my views.py

```
userID = request.POST.get("userID")
client = Customer(id=userID)
vegetables_id = request.POST.get("id")
quantity = request.POST.get("quantity")
v = Product(id=vegetables_id)
price = request.POST.get("price")
discount = request.POST.get("discount_price")
insert = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.get_or_create(
    profile=client,
    product = v,
    quantity=quantity,
    unitprice=price,
    discounted_amount = discount,
    discounted_unitprice = discount,
)

order_qs = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.filter(profile = client, product = v)
if order_qs.exists():
    order = order_qs[0]
    if order.objects.filter(profile = client).exists(): ==> The error is from this line
        insert.quantity += 1
        insert.save()
    else:
        order.quantity.add(insert)
else:
    order = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.create(
        profile=client,
        product=v,
        unitprice=price,
        quantity=1,
        discounted_amount=discount,
        discounted_unitprice=discount,
    )
    order.save()
```

this is my models.py

```
class CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Customer, 
                                on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                verbose_name="Client Account")
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, 
                                                on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                                verbose_name="Product")
    quantity = models.FloatField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True, default=1)

class Product(models.Model):
      product = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    contactNumber = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
```

[image]

this is my full traceback

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\LastProject\OnlinePalengke\customAdmin\views.py" in batchaddtocart
  943.         if order.objects.filter(profile = client).exists():

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in __get__
  176.             raise AttributeError("Manager isn't accessible via %s instances" % cls.__name__)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /batchaddtocart/
Exception Value: Manager isn't accessible via CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail instances
```

**Update**

when i tried this

```
order_qs = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.filter(profile=client,
    products = v,
    unitprice=price,
    quantity=1,
    discounted_amount = discount,
    discounted_unitprice = discount,)
for order in order_qs:
    if order.profile == client and order.products == v:
        insert.quantity += 1
        print(insert.quantity)
        insert.save()
insert.save()
```

when I tried mr vipul's answer, it did not add another record when the product exists in CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail, but the quantity is still the same it does not add 1 the quantity

**UPDATE (2)**

```
order_qs = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.filter(Q(profile__id__iexact=client) | Q(products__id__iexact=v)).distinct()

if order_qs.exists():
    insert.quantity += 1
    insert.save()
```

I received this error

[image]

Comment: What if you have more than one instance in your `order_qs` ?

Comment: it will add +1 in my quantity,

Comment: it will not add another record but it will add quantity if the order product is the same and the same user client

Comment: where do you passing the `object_manager` in `CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail` ?

Comment: @xxnora ive posted the updated code, please see

Answer (score 0):

```
if order_qs.exists():
    order = order_qs[0]
    if order.objects.filter(profile = client).exists():
```

Here the variable "order" is not a Class, but an instance of the Class CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail, hence you cannot use ".objects.filter.." on it

You should rather just go through the order_qs in a loop and check if the profile==client

```
for order in order_qs:
    if order.profile == client:
        insert.quantity+=1
insert.save()
```

OR directly filter on the qs, check the number of matching rows and add that many quantities

```
insert.quantity += order_qs.filter(profile=client).count()
insert.save()
```

Comment: it doesn't add 1 and quantity even if the product is the same

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do is... but you can put simple logic like this :

```
from django.db.models import Q

order_qs = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.filter(Q(profile__userID__iexact=client) | Q(product__vegetables_id__iexact=v) ).distinct()

if order_qs.exists():
    insert.quantity += 1
    insert.save()
```

Comment: it created another record

Comment: Please recheck to make sure you've implemented all the things perfectly except your logic in your code.

Comment: Related Field got invalid lookup: userID

Comment: when i tried this     """" order_qs = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.filter(Q(profile__id__iexact=client) | Q(products__id__iexact=v)).distinct() """"
 i get this error  """can't adapt type 'Customer' """